# How can i Alter TABLE all column from not null to null by one query of PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I migrate my data from MySQL Database to PostgreSQL Database and by mistaken i have all my column set not-null in PostgreSQL database.

After this i am facing issue for inserting data and have to uncheck not null manually, so is there any way to do for all column in table ( except id(PRIMARY KEY)  ).

i have this query also for single column but its also time consuming,

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ALTER COLUMN <column name> DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is built in functionality for this. But it's easy to write a function to do this. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_nullable(relation TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM pg_attribute
                WHERE attnotnull = TRUE AND attrelid=relation::regclass::oid AND attnum > 0 AND attname != 'id')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s ALTER COLUMN %s DROP NOT NULL', relation, rec.attname);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Set %.% nullable', relation, rec.attname;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT set_nullable('my_table');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that dropped columns never disappear from `pg_attribute`; always check the `attisdropped` flag.

Comment: It seems that it also sets `attnotnull` to `false` so this function still working : ) But thanks for a tip, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a new `CREATE TABLE noNULL` using the same structure as your current table and modify the `NULLable` field you need.

Then insert from old table

```
INSERT INTO noNULL 
      SELECT *
      FROM oldTable
```

then delete `oldTable` and rename `noNull -> oldTable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem with `SELECT INTO` is you cant set the table properties like types,  constrains, autonumeric. So I rather create the table first. Maybe you can elaborate why is discouraged?

Comment: @NickBarnes That comment is to me or `a_horse_whiit_no_name`? The idea is create the table with the same script you have the current table. `Select  INTO` doesnt do that

Comment: Sorry, I confused `insert into .. select` with `select ... into ..`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: It was for you. Even with the original `CREATE TABLE` script, you may still need to deal with dependent views and referencing foreign keys. And probably several other things I haven't thought of. Much simpler and safer to alter the existing table.

Comment: @NickBarnes yes, I miss a step. `then delete oldTable and rename noNull -> oldTable`  I agree alter the table should be better but OP complain about timing, and In my experience with postgres this aproach is much faster. Of course in a production enviroment maybe wont be viable.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Unfortunately, that doesn't help... You won't be allowed to drop `oldTable` without dropping the views and foreign keys first.